# Getting null arraylist from Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple android app where users can create folders and upload PDFs to them. The PDFs will be uploaded to Firebase storage and they will be fetched using their URLs which have been stored in Firestore. The fetched PDFs will be displayed in a RecyclerView. I am getting the URLs and names of pdfs and storing them in an arraylist. When I try to access this arraylist outside the OnCompleteListener , I get a NPE. I think this is because of the asynchronous nature of Firebase API.
So, I tried to use an interface after watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ofkvm97i0s) video by Alex Mamo.
But I'm still getting the same error. Is there any other way to either use onSuccessListener or OnCompleteListener without interface? And where should I attach the recyleradapter?

My code:

```
package com.example.XX;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ViewDocActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView fName;
    private RecyclerView pdfRecView;
    PdfAdapter adapter;
    List<String> pdfUrlList;
    List<String> pdfNameList;
    String folder_name;
    String pdfName;
    String pdfUrl;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_doc);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        folder_name = intent.getStringExtra("folderClicked");
        fName = findViewById(R.id.fName_tv);
        fName.setText(folder_name);

        pdfRecView = findViewById(R.id.pdfRecyclerView);
        pdfRecView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        db.collection(folder_name)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                pdfName = document.getString("name");
                                pdfUrl = document.getString("url");

                                Log.d("nameTest", "onComplete: " + pdfName);
                                Log.d("urlTest", "onComplete: " + pdfUrl);
                                pdfNameList.add(pdfName);
                                pdfUrlList.add(pdfUrl);
                            }

                        } else {
                            Log.d("TAG", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });

        adapter = new PdfAdapter(pdfUrlList, pdfNameList);//todo pdfNameList and url list should be fetched from Firestore before this
        pdfRecView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try initialising the array lists in onCreate before using them

```
pdfUrlList = new ArrayList<string>();

pdfNameList = new ArrayList<string>();
```

Comment: Such a stupid mistake from my side. Now I'm not getting the NPE. But also not able to see anything in the recyclerview. Anyways,thanks